# Creating lists of indexes based on 3d coordinate values: Is there a more efficient method than using a for loop in Python?

Tags: list, loops, for-loop, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to create a scipy sparse matrix and my input is a list of lists with 3d coordinates and values of that points. i got 1 million points in dataframe Such as:

```
data = pd.read_csv(r"D:\3d_coordinates_values.csv")  

x = data["IX"].values.tolist()  
y = data["IY"].values.tolist()  
rl = data["IZ"].values.tolist()
value = data["value"].values.tolist()  

b = [[x[i], y[i], rl[i], value[i]] for i in range(len(data))]
```

and I need to check their precedence to construct the sparse matrix.

```
il = []
jl = []
datal = []
for i, item in enumerate(b):
    for j, node in enumerate(b):
        if node[2]-item[2] == 1:
            if item[0]-node[0] == 1 or item[0] == node[0] or node[0]-item[0] == 1:
                if item[1]-node[1] == 1 or item[1] == node[1] or node[1]-item[1] == 1:
                    il.append(i)
                    jl.append(j)
                    datal.append(100000)
```

is there any faster alternative to create those il, jl and datal lists with this conditions. i am not sure to create the b = [[x[i], y[i], rl[i], value[i]] for i in range(len(data))] instead of checking this conditions on dataframe rows.

i tried to use list comprehension but it gives a syntax error for the code below

```
il=[i for (i,item) in enumerate(b) and (j,node) in enumerate(b) (if node[2]-item[2] == 1 (if item[0]-node[0] == 1 or item[0] == node[0] or node[0]-item[0] == 1 (if item[1]-node[1] == 1 or item[1] == node[1] or node[1]-item[1] == 1)))]
```